# Gibb's sampling where target prob distribution is itself a conditional joint distribution - p(x,y|t)

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, gibbs

[image]    I'm new to Gibb's sampling and need basic guidance. Say    p1,p2,q-> are Gaussian variables. p1->q<-p2 and q->x where x is a discrete variable (either 1 or 0). How do I go about Sampling (using Gibbs Sampling - a rough idea to begin) when the target distribution is p(p1,p2|x) given that x=1.

TIA.

Comment: what means  p1->t<-p2 ?

Comment: @quester : Sorry I edited it now and added an image for better understanding.

Comment: this is some kind of process or by these arrows you indicate dependency?

Comment: @quester: dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I assume you sample vertors (p1, p2, q, x), gibbs sampling says "keep n-1 coordinates from last result and sample next coordinate" here I would add "keep x=1"